# Access JSON array inside another json array

Tags: java, arrays, json, response

I am getting a response like this:

```
{
      "status": "Success",
      "data": [{
          "careTypeId": "10",
          "careTypeName": "Vacation Care",
          "daysOfinterest": ["Monday", "Tuesday"],
          "childDaysOfInterestId": "212"
      }, {
          "careTypeId": "10",
          "careTypeName": "Vacation Care",
          "daysOfinterest": ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Thursday"],
          "childDaysOfInterestId": "202"
      }],
      "message": "ChildDaysOf Interest"
  }
```

In this response I need to access the the data array and from that I need to get the `daysOfInterest` array.

Comment: It looks like its a string array, not json array. Show us your model class.

Answer (score 1):

First get Data Array like 
`jj` is your json object

```
JSONArray RecordList = new JSONArray(jj.getString("data"));
for (int i = 0; i < RecordList.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject list = RecordList.getJSONObject(i);
                         JSONArray RecordList1 = new JSONArray(list.getstring("daysOfinterest"));
Log.e("Test" , "get Result" + RecordList1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use org.json library, read more about it [here](http://www.json.org/)

First you have to convert jsonString to JSONObject and then from the JSONObject get data array and then you have to loop on that array to get daysOfInterest array.

Sample Code :

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonString = "{\n\"status\": \"Success\",\n\"data\": [{\n\"careTypeId\": \"10\",\n\"careTypeName\": \"Vacation Care\",\n\"daysOfinterest\": [\"Monday\", \"Tuesday\"],\n\"childDaysOfInterestId\": \"212\"\n}, {\n\"careTypeId\": \"10\",\n\"careTypeName\": \"Vacation Care\",\n\"daysOfinterest\": [\"Monday\", \"Tuesday\", \"Thursday\"],\n\"childDaysOfInterestId\": \"202\"\n }],\n\"message\": \"ChildDaysOf Interest\"\n }";
        try {
            JSONObject mainJsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONArray dataArray = mainJsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
            for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONArray daysOfInterestArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("daysOfinterest");
                for (int j = 0; j < daysOfInterestArray.length(); j++) {
                    System.out.println("Days of interest : " + daysOfInterestArray.get(j));
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Output :
Days of interest : Monday
Days of interest : Tuesday
Days of interest : Monday
Days of interest : Tuesday
Days of interest : Thursday